# how to build j2me applications using codename one?

Tags: codenameone

I create a new netbeans codename one project and it runs on codename emulator but  when i build the broject the application does not work on j2me device because there is no MIDlet.
there is an option called send j2me build but it is not available in my country i cant even signup for some
political reasons how to solve this problem ?
thank for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Google App Engine which we use for infrastructure is blocked in some countries. This is entirely out of our control. We are looking into the possibility of replacing the Google App Engine server architecture but that would take some time.

Technically you can build Codename One applications like you build LWUIT applications but it requires quite a bit of know how.

Comment: I'm from syria the codename one website opens but when i press signup  this is what i get  403. That’s an error.

Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server. 

We're sorry, but this service is not available in your country.  i'm usin firefox